# Modern Thai writing system and modern Khmer writing system and the sharing of Non-Sanskrit symbols

Tags: sanskrit, thai, lao, khmer

I understand that both old and modern Khmer and old and modern Thai, effected one another and share lots of words or "roots" of words.

### For example

#### Modern Thai words derived from Old Khmer

`ឆ្លាត`or `ឆ្លាស` (chlāt) | `ฉลาด`; smart
`ក្រុង` (groong)         | `กรุง`; city, as the common Thai name for Bangkok `กรุงเทพฯ` (groongthep)
`ខ្ទើយ` (ktəəy)         | `กะเทย`; Feminine transgender
`ច្រមុះ` (chrâmuh)       | `จมูก`; Nose
`ច្រើន` (craən)         | `เจริญ`; prosperous
`ភ្លើង` (/pləəŋ/)       | `เพลิง`; fire
`ទន្លេ` (tonle)        | `ทะเล`; sea
`ថ្នល់` (thnâl)          | `ถนน`; road

#### Modern Thai words and structures shared with general Khmer

- อาจ “can” (the final จ gives away the Khmer origin)
- โดย: “by way of”
- ตำนาน “legend”
- สำหรับ: “for”
- เสมียน “clerk”
- หรือ: “or”
- นัก prefix for profession (meaning “a person” in khmer), as in นักเรียน and guess what, เรียน also comes from Khmer.
- ผสม “to mix”
- เพราะ: “because”
- เรียน “to learn”
- สะอาด “clean”
- ตำบล “district” (from old Khmer “cluster of houses”)
- ตรวจ “to examine” and ตำรวจ “police” (you see the khmer coining of words as in “to walk”)
- ถนน “street”
- ทะเบียน “register”
- วัด “monastery” and also “to measure” (both from Mon-Khmer root meaning “to make a circle, to mark the boundary”)

#### In Wikipedia article "Thai language" it was written:

> Royal Thai (ราชาศัพท์, racha sap): influenced by Khmer
>
> `and`:
>
> Thai is written in the Thai script, an abugida written from left to right. Many scholars believe[citation needed] that it is derived from the Khmer script.
>
> Certainly the numbers were lifted directly from Khmer

Khmer, Thai and Lao numbers are presented below:

**Value | Khmer | Thai | Lao**


0 | ០ | ๐ | ໐
1 | ១ | ๑ | ໑
2 | ២ | ๒ | ໒
3 | ៣ | ๓ | ໓
4 | ៤ | ๔ | ໔
5 | ៥ | ๕ | ໕
6 | ៦ | ๖ | ໖
7 | ៧ | ๗ | ໗
8 | ៨ | ๘ | ໘
9 | ៩ | ๙ | ໙

### My question

Do the writing systems of the **modern versions** of the two languages share anything in common besides Some Sanskrit-derived symbols (whatever these Sanskrit derived symbols might be)?

Comment: Will you clarify your question? What do you mean by "Sanskrit-derived symbols"? Sanskrit is a language, not a writing system, one cannot derive symbols from a language.

Comment: Hello @YellowSky by `Sanskrit-derived symbols` I meant to the letters (consonants/vowels), diacritics and any other communication symbol, available in the writing system of the Sanskrit language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbols the Thai and Khmer scripts share but which are not used in Classical Sanskrit are few. They are these:

1. Consonant: Khmer `ឡ` [lɑː] and Thai `ฬ` [ḷa]. This symbol is used in Pali and Vedic Sanskrit words for the sound [ḷ] which does not exist in Classical Sanskrit.
2. These vowel diacritics: Khmer `ឹ` [ə]/[ɨ] and Thai `◌ึ` [ɯ] and their long counterparts; Khmer `ឺ` [əɨ]/[ɨː] and Thai `◌ื` [ɯː].